# How to push a docker image to ecr repo in moto server

Tags: docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr, moto

I am running moto server using the command

```
moto_server ecr -p 5000 -H 0.0.0.0
```

I created an ECR repo using the moto server with the command,

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name test --endpoint-url http://localhost:5000 --region us-east-1
```

Now can anybody please help on how to push a docker image to this ecr repo created using moto server?

Comment: Is this moto server  a mock of aws ecr?

Comment: yes moto server is a mock for many aws services.
https://github.com/spulec/moto

Comment: ECR is a docker registry which is a server running in some port. If moto is able to mock it, some endpoints should be available to test. Use this to test your mocked ecr server: `curl -X GET https://myregistry:5000/v2/_catalog`. I think in your case is localhost. Also try to get the used port with `netstat -tulpn` para linux or `netstat -aon` for windows. If this works. The image upload is a piece of cake :b

Comment: TIL moto exists :) . If this was classic ECR before being able to push an image you would first need to authenticate ([see here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html)) and then you'd need to push an image using something along the lines of `docker push aws_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/YOURIMAGE:TAG`. Eager to learn know exactly how moto mock all this (if it does).

Comment: @JRichardsz There is no private registry in case of the ECR by moto. Please check my answer for the workaround.

Comment: @mreferre Moto is just a mock for AWS. Hence the docker calls to pull or push an image is not possible. https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/3852

Answer (score 1):

After going through the code I found that the `put-image` command actually adds an image to the repository. In the case of [ECR by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/put-image.html) this command is used by AWS to add metadata of the image uploaded via the docker push command.

```
# aws ecr put-image --repository-name test --region us-east-1 --image-manifest test --endpoint-url http://localhost:5000 --image-tag v1
{
    "image": {
        "registryId": "012345678910",
        "repositoryName": "test",
        "imageId": {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:a6698ae96409579a4f8ac96f5e5f276467b3f62d184c9e6db537daeedb9dd939",
            "imageTag": "v1"
        },
        "imageManifest": "test"
    }
}

# aws ecr list-images --repository-name test --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url http://localhost:5000
{
    "imageIds": [
        {
            "imageDigest": "i don't know",
            "imageTag": "v1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Luckily my code doesn't need to push or pull image from the ECR repo. This method might not work if that is the case.